# angular reactive form cross field custom validation not working in edit

Tags: angular

I am using Reactive form in my angular app. i am using custom validation to check if end time is later than the start time. When it is in add page, the validation is working fine. but when i edit the record the validators does not seems to be working.

```
createForm() {
        this.sessionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          sessionCode: [''],
          sessionName: ['', Validators.required],
          sessionTimeGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
            startTime: ['', Validators.required],
            endTime: ['', Validators.required]
          }, { validator: SessionTimesValidator('startTime','endTime')}),
          disabled: [''],
        },);

}

import { FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export function SessionTimesValidator(startTimeControlName: string, endTimeControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } | null => {

        const startTimeControl = formGroup.get(startTimeControlName);
        const endTimeControl = formGroup.get(endTimeControlName)

        const startTimeValue = startTimeControl.value;
        const endTimeValue = endTimeControl.value;

        if (startTimeControl.pristine || endTimeControl.pristine) {
            return null;
        }

        let validationResult = null;

        if(startTimeValue !== null && endTimeValue !== null) {
            const sTime = moment(`${startTimeValue.hour}:${startTimeValue.minute}`,'HH:mm');
            const eTime = moment(`${endTimeValue.hour}:${endTimeValue.minute}`,'HH:mm');
            if(eTime.isBefore(sTime)) {
                validationResult =  {'sessionTime': {value: 'End Time must be after the Start Time'}};
            }
        }

        return validationResult;
    };
}




 saveSession(): void {
        this.submitted = true;

        if (!this.sessionForm.invalid) {

          const sessionToSave = SessionFormMapper.mapToModel(this.sessionForm.value);


        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: updated with the save method i call when i submit the form. It is initiating the validation after changing the control couple of times.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

To update your form,

you need to patch your form with the new value.

```
this.sessionForm.patch({
    ... 
  },{emitEvent:false});
```

Be carreful with infinite loop. If you save your form automatically on validation. Without the `emitEvent:false`, the updated value will start the validation which will save again... and again.